# how to highlight part of a JLabel at runtime?

Tags: java, jlabel, overriding

I have a JLabel inside a JPanel. I'm using Netbeans IDE for the GUI of my java program (free design, and no Layout Manager).

At runtime I need to highlight a part of my JLabel. Highlighting a part of JLabel can be done as said here : [How to highlight part of a JLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533967/how-to-highlight-part-of-a-jlabel)

I don't know how to do that in run time, I mean I already have a JLabel, now how can I override it's paintComponent() method for that purpose ?

Comment: It would probably be easier to use a JTextField with no border and set to transparent - IMHO

Comment: my problem is not how to do highlighting, it's how to do what is said in that page in runtime...

Comment: just change text with html inside, never tried, maybe you will need to call repaint()

Comment: because of reasons I can not use HTML in my java program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an illustrative example of the answer given by Tikhon Jelvis in the post you mentioned, all you need is to add some fields (in this example `start` and `end`) to indicate the regions to be highlighted, and use a method (`highlightRegion` in this example) to set these fields:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Highlighting");
        frame.setSize(300, 100);

        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText("Money does not buy happiness");
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        label.highlightRegion(3, 15);

        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class Label extends JLabel
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int start;
        private int end;

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();

            String startString = getText().substring(0, start);
            String text = getText().substring(start, end);

            int startX = fontMetrics.stringWidth(startString);
            int startY = 0;

            int length = fontMetrics.stringWidth(text);
            int height = fontMetrics.getHeight();

            g.setColor(new Color(0x33, 0x66, 0xFF, 0x66));
            g.fillRect(startX, startY, length, height);

            super.paint(g);
        }

        public void highlightRegion(int start, int end)
        {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }
    }

}
```

Notice the use of `label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);` to simplify things. If you don't use it then you need to do extra computations to determine the exact vertical location of the region to be highlighted.

Comment: thanx, but it doesn't solve my problem. I MUST use netbeans free design tool for my GUI, and these works can not be done in such situation as Netbeans only allows me to use JLabel, not it's inheritors...

Comment: @user1986618 create a new label class (called something like HighlightLabel) in your project based on the code from the previous question. Do a clean and build on the project. Create a new form, drag the class (from the project) onto the form. It's even possible to add it to the palette if you really want to

Comment: @MadProgrammer Great !!!! so much thank you for your amazing answer! I didn't know such works are possible in Netbeans !!! +1