# Highlighting the text of a jtable cell

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to highlight the text of a jtable cell.
    This is my code:
    when i am getting the editor for specified cell in testingHighlighter method and trying to        highlight the text in that editor component. please help me where i am wrong.

```
public class test extends JFrame
{
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JTable table;
    String col[] = {"Name","Address","Phone","test"};

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        test t = new test();
        t.start();
        t.testingHightligher();

    }

    public void start()
    {

         model = new DefaultTableModel(col,2); 
         table=new JTable(model){@Override
         public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {

                return true;
            }};

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);

        setColumnEditor( table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 0 ), new Object[] { "AND",
            "OR" }, "Logical Operator" );


        Object[] objs = new Object[] { "==", "=" };
        setColumnEditor( table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 2 ), objs, "Logical Operator");

        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor( field );

        editor.setClickCountToStart( 1 );
        TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 3 );

        col.setCellEditor( editor );

        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer.setToolTipText( "click to edit" );
        col.setCellRenderer( renderer );

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 0 ).setPreferredWidth( 25 );
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 1 ).setPreferredWidth( 120 );
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 2 ).setPreferredWidth( 25 );
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 3 ).setPreferredWidth( 100 );

        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed( false );

        table.setValueAt("csanuragjain",0,3);

        add(pane);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500,400);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void setColumnEditor( TableColumn col, Object[] editValues, String renderTip )
    {
        JComboBox comboBox = null;
        if( editValues != null )
        {
            comboBox = new JComboBox( editValues );
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox = new JComboBox();
        }

        comboBox.setMaximumRowCount( 6 );

        DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox );
        editor.setClickCountToStart( 2 );
        col.setCellEditor( editor );

        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

        renderer.setToolTipText( renderTip );
        col.setCellRenderer( renderer );


        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = col.getHeaderRenderer();
        if( headerRenderer instanceof DefaultTableCellRenderer )
        {
            ( (DefaultTableCellRenderer) headerRenderer ).setToolTipText( "test" );
        }
    }

    void testingHightligher()
    {
        Object value = table.getValueAt(0, 3);
        JTextField field = (JTextField) table.getColumnModel().getColumn( 3 ).getCellEditor().getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, true, 0, 3);

        try
        {

            field.getHighlighter().addHighlight(0, 3, new javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.RED ));

        }
        catch(BadLocationException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



Please help me where i am wrong..
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem in next, you try to highlight text in TableCellEditor, which you see when editing a cell of `JTable`, but in that moment you see only CellRenderer, you can fix your code by adding `table.editCellAt(0, 3);` at start of `testingHightligher()` method. Also call your test like next code in your `main()`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
              t.testingHightligher();
        }
});
```

IF you want to highlight text in `JTable` while it isn't edit, you need to use [`TableCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html). [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) is tutorial for that.

Example :

```
TableCellRenderer r = new TableCellRenderer() {
        JTextField f = new JTextField();

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
            if(arg1 != null){
                f.setText(arg1.toString());
                try {
                    f.getHighlighter().addHighlight(0,3,new javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.RED));
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                f.setText("");
                f.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
            }
            return f;
        }
    };
```

You need somthin like this, also I recommend you replace `JTextField` here by `JLabel` and hightligh it like [written here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3537009/2894369)

EDIT:

Here is full example for you, it works, watch and examine it:

```
 public class Form extends JFrame {

    private String textForSearch = "";
    private JTable t;

    public Form() {
        DefaultTableModel model;
        t = new JTable(model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new Object[]{1}));
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
            model.addRow(new Object[]{i});
        }
        for(int i =0;i<t.getColumnCount();i++){
            t.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(getRenderer());
        }

        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(t);
        final RightPanel right = new RightPanel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private TableCellRenderer getRenderer() {
        return new TableCellRenderer() {
            JTextField f = new JTextField();

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
                if(arg1 != null){
                    f.setText(arg1.toString());
                    String string = arg1.toString();
                    if(string.contains(textForSearch)){
                        int indexOf = string.indexOf(textForSearch);
                        try {
                            f.getHighlighter().addHighlight(indexOf,indexOf+textForSearch.length(),new javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.RED));
                        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    f.setText("");
                    f.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
                }
                return f;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Form().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class RightPanel extends JPanel{


        public RightPanel(){
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            c.gridy = 0;
            final JTextField f = new JTextField(5);
            add(f,c);
            JButton b = new JButton("search");
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    textForSearch = f.getText();
                    t.repaint();
                }
            });
            c.gridy++;
            add(b,c);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can i change the formatting of a tableCellRendererComponent after getting it. like if i do  JTextField field = (JTextField) table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).getCellRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, true, true, 0, 3);
and after that i highlight the cell text with JTextField highlighter. i tried this but couldn't succeed.. would it be possible.??

Comment: I think no, why you can't use my example?

Comment: In my case renderer is already defined for table columns and i want to implement search for this table. my requirement is to highlight the searched text in particular cell. How can i achieve this behavior ?

Comment: Do it with custom renderer, write text in textField then in renderer search it in value, and if it has your searchText highligh it

Comment: What if custom renderer is already defined for jtable columns. Can i do it without changing the custom renderer??

Comment: @Akki I think no, don't fear to change default renderer in last column.

Comment: For one column you can use one Renderer and one Editor, write your logic in it. In my answer I post a link to tutorial for that do you read it?

Comment: Let me elaborate the my use case first.. I have a jtable it has a custom renderer defined for its columns, i am using Jtextfield as rendering component. I have different search dialog which contains the text field and a button. when i click on search button i want to highlight cell text where the searched text found. Now the Problem is, table columns are already rendered.. and it is not possible to pass searched string to that custom renderer. Can i override the custom renderer for particular cell of a row.?? I have the row no. and column no. where i want to highlight the cell text..

Comment: I edited my post, it has full code for you, I think it's answer for you, mark as solution.